# How do make karabiner type Ä?

Tags: karabiner

I'm trying to map å (option-a) to ä (option-u, a) and Å (option-shift-a) to Ä (option-u, shift-a).  I was able to figure out the first one:

```
{
    "description": "German: å to ä",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "a",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "option"
                    ],
                    "optional": [
                        "any"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "u",
                    "modifiers": ["left_option"]
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "a"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        },
    ]
}
```

but I'm having trouble figuring out the second one.  If I hold down shift, I end up with ¨A, not Ä.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *Karabiner-EventViewer* or Apple's *Keyboard Viewer* while doing it manually to see **shift-option-u** gets a bare <kbd>¨</kbd>, **option-u a** gets <kbd>ä</kbd> and **option-u shift-a** gets <kbd>Ä</kbd> so was:

```
{"title": "German: å to ä",
 "rules": [{"description": "⌥a to ä and ⇧⌥A to Ä.",
        "manipulators": [
          {"from": {"key_code": "a", "modifiers": {"mandatory": ["option"],
                               "optional": ["caps_lock", "control", "command"]}},
           "to": [{"key_code": "u", "modifiers": ["option"]},
              {"key_code": "a"}],
           "type": "basic"},
          {"from": {"key_code": "a", "modifiers": {"mandatory": ["option", "shift"],
                               "optional": ["caps_lock", "control", "command"]}},
           "to": [{"key_code": "u", "modifiers": ["option"]},
              {"key_code": "a", "modifiers": ["shift"]}],
           "type": "basic"}]}]}
```